# How to Bind dropdown from anonymous class values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, anonymous-function, anonymous-types, anonymous-class

I want to populate a dropdown with values A,Band C.The below code works for create only,not for edit.

```
 ViewBag.UserType = new[] { new SelectListItem { Text = "A", Value = "1", Selected = false }, new SelectListItem { Text = "B", Value = "2", Selected = false }, new SelectListItem { Text = "C", Value = "3", Selected = false } };
```

So I created an anonymous class. I have an anonymous class like below.

```
var Roles= new[]
            {    new { Id =1,UserType="A" },
                 new {Id=2,UserType="B" },
                 new {Id=3,UserType="B" }            
            };
          ViewBag.Type = Roles.ToList();
```

But i dont know how to fill dropdown in View.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserType, ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.UserType).Select(option => new SelectListItem
                                     {
                                         Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Text),
                                         Value = option.Value.ToString(),
                                         Selected = (Model != null) && (option.Value == (Model.UserType).ToString())
                                     }),"Select")
```

What changes should i make in the view

Comment: What is the type of your model, the one which you send to the view please ?

Answer (score 0):

Add following properties to your ViewModel class -

```
    public SelectList Roles
    {
        get
        {
            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = "1",
                Text = "A",
            });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = "2",
                Text = "B",
            });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = "3",
                Text = "C",
            });

            return new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text");
        }
    }

    public int SelectedRole { get; set; }
```

and bind in View as follows -

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRole, Model.Roles)
```